# Check conditions from two lists

Tags: list, python-3.x

I have 2 lists, `excludeName` and `excludeZipCode`, and a list of dictionaries `search_results`. I need to exclude some of the dictionaries from the list they are being copied in to (`search_copy`) based on several conditions. The index of the excluded name is the same as the index of the excluded zip code. Currently I am completely baffled, though I have tried many different ways to iterate over them and exclude. Another problem I've been having is having businesses added many times.

```
excludeName = ['Burger King', "McDonald's", 'KFC', 'Subway', 'Chic-fil-a', 'Wawa', 'Popeyes Chicken and Biscuits', 'Taco Bell', "Wendy's", "Arby's"]
excludeZip = ['12345', '54321', '45123', '39436', '67834', '89675', '01926', '28645', '27942', '27932']
while i < len(search_results):
        for business in search_results:
            for name in excludeName:
                occurrences = [h for h, g in enumerate(excludeName) if g == name]
                for index in occurrences:
                    if (business['name'] != excludeName[index]) and (business['location']['zip_code'] != excludeZip[index]):
                        search_copy.append(business)
        i += 1
```

Here's an example dictionary:

```
{
    'location': {
        'zip_code': '12345'
    },
    'name': 'Burger King'
}
```

Comment: Does the index of each business entity inside your dictionary search_results have to match that of excludeName and excludeZip? Or as long as any excludeName/excludeZip indexed pair match any entry of a business its to not be copied?

Comment: @Edward the indexes of the name and zip have to be the same. That's where I slip up.

Comment: I understand those are paired, but does the index of businesses in search_result matter? Are you wanting to check all businesses against all excluded Pair?

Comment: Yeah. All businesses against all excluded pairs. Sorry if I didn't make that clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works by first copying your list of business entities, then removes those that has any matches in the excludedName/excludeZip pair.

```
search_copy=search_results[:]
for j in search_results:
    for i in range(0,len(excludeName)):
        if (j['name'] == excludeName[i]) and (j['location']['zip_code'] == excludeZip[i]):
            search_copy.remove(j)
```

In theory for best performance you want to iterate the bigger list first, which  I would assume is the list of businesses

Comment: I'll test this out in the morning, I'm heading off to bed.

Comment: Ok, I did test it against your data. Works fine.

Comment: @TheWrenchintheSystem You get a chance to test this code yet?

Comment: It gives an index out of bounds error if search_results is longer than excludeName.

Comment: @TheWrenchintheSystem oops I used that length from your code above when it really should be length of the excludedPair lists. I will switch that now